# need enabled Apex classes of particular profile

Tags: apex, soql, profile

Requirement-Need to fetch all enabled classes of profile.If i am using package.xml and retrieved the classes then all classes are coming with true and false property,so its difficult to create a list of enabled clasess.
Is there any query or way i can get all Enabled clasess of profile

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT NamespacePrefix, Name FROM ApexClass 
WHERE Id IN 
    (SELECT SetupEntityId 
     FROM SetupEntityAccess 
     WHERE Parent.Profile.Name = :profileName)
```

Replace :profileName with the name you're looking for. You can run this query in the Data Loader if you want a CSV file.